# 'List[Element]' object has no attribute 'Name'

Tags: python, api, revit, pyrevit

I have two issues

1. level list does not contain name or other parameter why this error is comming to every element I am collecting 
   [image]
2. `Urinals.Symbol.FamilyName("Type Comments").AsString() == "Urinal")`: is not working

```
from pyrevit.output import charts
from pyrevit import script
from pyrevit import revit, DB
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import FilteredElementCollector, BuiltInCategory
__context__ = 'zerodoc'

from System.Collections.Generic import List
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument

from rpw import db, ui, doc
from pyrevit.framework import List
from pyrevit import revit, DB
room_filter = "WORK"


import rpw
from rpw import doc, uidoc, DB

# GET ALL ROOMS IN MODEL
rooms = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_Rooms)
Urinals = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_PlumbingFixtures).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
ub_count = 0
MRest_rooms = []
WRest_rooms = []
ADARest_rooms = []
Urinal_count = 0

#for u in Urinals:
#   if (Urinals.Symbol.FamilyName("Type Comments").AsString() == "Urinal"):
#    Urinal_count +=1
for r in rooms:
    if (r.Level.Name != 'CONTAINER LEVEL') and (r.LookupParameter("Name").AsString() == "M RESTROOM"):
        MRest_rooms.append(r)
    if (r.Level.Name != 'CONTAINER LEVEL') and (r.LookupParameter("Name").AsString() == "W RESTROOM"):
        WRest_rooms.append(r)

print "Number of Male Rest Room =",len(MRest_rooms)
print "Number of Female Rest Room =", len(WRest_rooms)

Level = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
print "Number of Level =",len(Level)
for i in Level:
 a = Level.Name
 print a
```

Comment: can you share the entire traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is this line:

```
Level = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
print "Number of Level =",len(Level)
for i in Level:
 a = Level.Name
 print a
```

It should be:

```
Level = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
print "Number of Level =",len(Level)
for i in Level:
 a = i.Name
 print a
```

Inside of the `for` loop you called `Level.Name` where `Level` is actually a list of levels. Hence the exception.

Same issue with the commented out code:

```
for u in Urinals:
   if (Urinals.Symbol.FamilyName("Type Comments").AsString() == "Urinal"):
    Urinal_count +=1
```

Replace with:

```
for u in Urinals:
   if (u.Symbol.FamilyName("Type Comments").AsString() == "Urinal"):
    Urinal_count +=1
```

Comment: Would you approve the answer if that solved your issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at it in the debugger and you will see for yourself.

Comment: Sorry still did not get it... help